# Remove planes if boolean = true not working

Tags: hashmap, c++-cli

I'm trying to remove my planes when the user inputs that they have landed.  This doesn't work.  Can anyone see any problems with my code to why it does not work.

Here is my code:

**Plane**

```
static boolean isLanded;
public boolean isLanded() {
        return isLanded;
    }


    public void setLanded(boolean isLanded) {
        this.isLanded = isLanded;
    }
```

**PlaneStore**

```
public void removeLandedPlanes(PlaneStore store)
    {
        if(Plane.isLanded = true)
        {
            airlineMap.remove(store);
        }
    }
```

**MainApp**

```
case 3:
                    System.out.println("Remove Landed Planes.");
                    airlineMap.removeLandedPlanes(airlineMap);
                    airlineMap.print();
                    break;
```

**HashMap declaration in PlaneStore**

```
HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Plane>> airlineMap;

    public PlaneStore() 
    {
        airlineMap = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Plane>>();
    }
```

And then in main PlaneStore `airlineMap = new PlaneStore();`

What this seems to have done is make every plane object to have `isLanded` to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(Plane.isLanded = true)
```

Note that this is **assigning** the value `true` to `Plane.isLanded`. You want to use the comparison operator `==` instead of `=`.

```
if(Plane.isLanded == true)
```

And since this is a `boolean` already, you should actually leave out the `== true` completely:

```
if(Plane.isLanded)
```

Comment: For some reason everything in the plane store, isLanded is set to false.  So i cant even check if that works :S.

Comment: That's because `isLanded` is `static` - that means there's only one copy of the variable, shared by all `Plane` objects. That's probably not what you want - remove the `static` keyword in the declaration of `isLanded`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to `Plane.isLanded`, not testing for equality

```
 if(Plane.isLanded = true)
```

should be

```
 if(Plane.isLanded == true)
```

You could avoid this altogether with simply

```
if (Plane.isLanded)
```

or put the constant term on the left

```
if (true == Plane.isLanded)
```

which would not have compiled had you made your initial mistake of `=` instead of `==`